# How do I generate IDs for objects imported from a .dae-file that will be the same the next load?

Tags: three.js, collada, sketchup

I'm building a CMS around THREE.js and I need to keep track of objects through some attribute that doesn't change when loading the file the next time. I'm using DAE-files that are exported from the Sketchup format .skp. The attributes "id" and "uuid" appears to be generated on each load. Sometimes the "name"-attribute have the format "group_41" or "instance_58", but it's often empty which makes it unreliable.

I'm not locked in using .DAE if anyone has another solution, but it's heavily favoured because it's easier to export from Sketchup than having to go through Blender to create the JSON-format (which from my experience also requires a lot of tweaks and settings to work properly).

Does anyone have any experience with this, or a workaround in either Sketchup or another third-party plugin/software to create lasting IDs?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found a simple solution: group the faces/"sides" together, that way they get the "group_nn"-name format. From there you can select the children-meshes of that group to work with. Note that the individual faces don't get any names, but we can still find them through their parent. To group in SketchUp, this worked for me:[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1):

In SketchUp 2017, `Entities` have a `persistent_id` which will not change in a SketchUp model between sessions.

You could write a SketchUp Ruby script to rename all Groups to their persistent_id and then you can track the Entities from the SketchUp model to the export file.

http://ruby.sketchup.com/Sketchup/Entity.html#persistent_id-instance_method

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!